# I find the behavior of the the following TypeScript snippet inconsistent. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below, assigning a string literal to a variable of basic (primitive) type `string` is fine: `let s3: string = "s"`.

But shouldn't TypeScript disallow the assignment from a string literal to variable of non-basic `String` type: `let s1: String = "s"`? Especially, given that later `s1 instanceof String` is `false`:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzgjAXBAymATgSwHYHMIF4IBEUBA3BAPTkQYD2EIKKNKAsAFCiRQBMCy62PNRAB3JKkxYAFEQIBKMu07QAzAigTB+WSXYBjGhig1QAOmA1psCJg0BDDHpA0AZuIFY5FKi7vAoIPqGxmYWVtw2RmAOTq7ukl6UEKgAroFsBkYmIOaWUta4hdDcCt4Qvv7pmSE5YfkweEVQKqVJqSC6GcHZudJgAJ4ADs5usIlURJpYBEFZoXkDw3E844Q0AEYAViB6YDNdc7ULQyOqq5Me+5TVPXXNkfaOpxoeqwxMrGxAA).

```
let s1: String = "s"; // no error here
let s2: String = new String("s"); 
let s3: string = "s";
console.log(s1 instanceof String) // false
console.log(s2 instanceof String) // true
console.log(s1 === s2); // false
console.log(s1 === s3); // true;
console.log(typeof(s1)) // "string"
console.log(typeof(s2)) // "object"
console.log(typeof(s3)) // "string"
//console.log(s3 instanceof string) // error
```

The generated JS code is this (with TS 4.0, `-t ESNext t.ts`):

```
let s1 = "s"; // no error here
let s2 = new String("s");
let s3 = "s";
console.log(s1 instanceof String); // false
console.log(s2 instanceof String); // true
console.log(s1 === s2); // false
console.log(s1 === s3); // true;
console.log(typeof (s1)); // "string"
console.log(typeof (s2)); // "object"
console.log(typeof (s3)); // "string"
//console.log(s3 instanceof String) // error
```

I understand how things work in this JavaScript code, but why does TS default to generate it like that: a primitive value rather than an implicit instance of `String`. I'd rather expect `let s1 = new String("s")`, or an error.

I mean, if the variable `v` is of non-basic type `Type` in TypeScript, I'd expect `v instanceof Type` be `true`, but that's not the case for `s1`.

Is this behavior defined in the specs somewhere?

Comment: it's weird!  and would cause so many problems if you consider (s1 instanceof String) should be true !

Comment: Interesting. But do you really use `new String` somewhere? (just curious)

Comment: @AlekseyL., not really, I've come across this accidentally. Also, I do more work in vanilla JavaScript than in TypeScript, and whenever I need to check if something is a string, I've learnt to do this: `stringVar.constructor === String`. That works across the board and in TS, too ([fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzgjAXBAymATgSwHYHMIF4IBEUBA3BALABQokUATAsutnhBiAO5KqZYAURAgEoyVGtADMCKDxb5BJKgGMA9higrQAOmAr+sLavWoArkrAqUeXPia8hytRu279dQ09PnL127KwOlEbOIDp6fFASHsYoZhZWNn7MAVRAA)).  It doesn't work across realms, but this one does: `stringVar.constructor.name === 'String'`.

Comment: You actually forgot a case: `let s4: string = String("s");` :-)

Comment: @BartHofland that's a nice case indeed, to add even more confusion :) Though I wouldn't question this one, as it predictably behaves exactly the same as with plain string literal assignment. `String` is used as a cast here, so it returns a primitive string value.

Comment: I saw this in TS handbook: `It can be tempting to think that the types Number, String, Boolean, Symbol, or Object are the same as the lowercase versions recommended above. These types do not refer to the language primitives however, and almost never should be used as a type.` Makes sense?

Comment: @Anatoly it makes perfect sense, that's why I'd expect TypeScript to fail the `let s1: String = "s"` assignment with an error, to protect me from myself. As it does for `let s1: object = "s"`. I actually thing the behavior I described is a bug, but don't want to spam the TS GitHub repro with a new issue until I'm sure.

Comment: I suppose they intentionally provided an implicit cast from `string` to `String` but not vice versa. `        let s: String = '';
        let ss = 'aaa';
        s = ss;
        ss = s;
` the last line has an error `Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.ts(2322)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: one thing TypeScript cannot and will not do is take code like `let s1: String = "s";` and emit it to JavaScript as `let s1 = new String("s");`.  That's because TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript.  TypeScript's emitter will strip off any type-system-specific features like type annotations.  If what is left is valid JavaScript in the target version of JavaScript, that will be emitted as-is.  There really is no other option but `let s1 = "s";` for the emitted JavaScript.

It is specifically a [non-goal of the TypeScript language design](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) to "add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system". So any suggestion or expectation of this sort should be abandoned.

---

Now: why do they allow you to assign a `string` value to a variable of `String` type?  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#3448](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13488) (although the opener of that issue was arguing that types like `string` and `String` should be mutually assignable, whereas you are suggesting that they should be mutually *incompatible*... but the same topics arise, so see that issue for more info).

Currently, primitive types like `string` are considered assignable *to* the interfaces defined for their wrapper object types like `String`, but not vice versa.  That is, in TypeScript, `string` is a (proper) *subtype* of `String`.  This is all working as intended, although at least one of the language designers described the situation as [a landmine](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13488#issuecomment-272613131).

So why is the above behavior (where `string` is assignable to `String`) working as intended?  To try to make some sense of it, let's talk about a few usually-desirable features of TypeScript that combine to give this somewhat unfortunate behavior.

---

The first is the relationship between named class constructor values and the interface type of instances they construct.  Let's say we have a class constructor named `Foo`; this will exist at runtime (either as an explicit ES2015 `class` or as an ES5 `function`) and we can use it to construct instances (e.g., `new Foo("someArg");`) and test against instances (e.g., `val instanceof Foo`).  Then, generally speaking, there will be an `interface` in TypeScript's static type system, also named `Foo`, corresponding to the type of the *instances* created by the constructor.  So if we call `const foo = new Foo("someArg");` then when we inspect `foo` in our TypeScript IDE it will probably show us `const foo: Foo;`.

This same-name relationship happens automatically when we write a `class` in TypeScript.  For library declarations not using the `class` syntax, this is also the usual convention; there will be a named interface for the constructor called something like `FooConstructor` with a newable signature like `{ new (arg: string) => Foo }`, and then the constructor value will be declared like `declare var Foo: FooConstructor;` (see [this part of the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) for more info)... which amounts to the same thing: `Foo` is the name of a constructor whose instances are of type `Foo`.

This convention is followed for `String` (and `Number` and `Boolean`).  There is a [`StringConstructor` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d057f7a9926a5466e6c65656a0b5117849df2e36/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L517-L527) and `String` is declared to be a value of that type.  And when we call `new String()` on a `StringConstructor` we get a value assignable to the [`String` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d057f7a9926a5466e6c65656a0b5117849df2e36/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L394-L515).

---

The next thing is that TypeScript's type system is [*structural*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not *nominal*.  If type `A` and type `B` have the same *shape* (i.e., their properties and methods have the same names and the same types), then TypeScript considers them the same *type*.  Even if `interface A { }` and `interface B { }` are declared in two different places and do not mention each other, they can still be the same type.

This combined with the prior feature leads to some weirdness with the behavior of `instanceof`:

```
class Foo {
    x: string;
    constructor(x: string) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

const foo: Foo = new Foo("x");
console.log(foo instanceof Foo); // true

const bar: Foo = { x: "x" }; // also accepted
console.log(bar instanceof Foo); // false
```

I'm allowed to say that `bar` is of type `Foo`, because the `Foo` interface only cares that it has a property named `x` of type `string`.  There's no requirement that a value of type `Foo` be constructed by the `Foo` constructor.  So `val instanceof Foo`'s behavior can't be cleanly represented in TypeScript.  Mismatches of this sort, where JavaScript cares about a value's provenance but TypeScript does not, are unfortunate but not easily avoidable because of TypeScript's reliance on structural compatibility.

---

Finally, primitives in JavaScript are wrapped with wrapper objects of the corresponding types whenever you try to look at properties or call methods on them.  This gives primitives like `string` the *appearance* of being objects with an interface like `String`.  And so, TypeScript allows you to treat a `string` like a `String`, by giving it [*apparent members*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c320c884d6f8422dc0bebb0e80d276379e5d5b88/doc/spec.md#3.11.1) from the `String` interface.  This is why you can write `"foo".toUpperCase()` without a warning in TypeScript.

---

Put all these three together and you end up with the mess from your question. TypeScript's `String` interface just means "this thing has the same properties and methods of a `String` object" and not "this thing was produced by calling `new` on the  `String` constructor".  Nothing prevents you from writing `const str: String = "x";`.  But of course `typeof str === typeof new String()` will be `false`, and any other test whose behavior depends on the difference between a primitive and its wrapper object will be unobservable in TypeScript.  It's a consequence of a few different useful features of TypeScript interacting in unpleasant ways.

It is therefore [recommended](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object) *never* to use the wrapper object types. If you write the type `String` in your code, it's probably not what you want, so don't do it.  Such advice may be a poor substitute for compiler warnings, but right now that seems to be the best that can be done.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.0.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoA8Bc0EALgE4CWAdgOYDcG20w8FxJArsEfCQBT6GlKVAJQp6DbEQAWZCADoc0ALy46mbAF8MW9BiYsi0AGaICCJCooBTAO5xEPAEQ5HwtfojwQVuSHhUeEyRKYjAKYCt4I3t4N2gAenjoUjYrDD1mYmgAIzASM0RlFFwCZ0doDRoEpLAQT2gwYAiAByIrABMMli8fPwDckmgQojCIqJi4xONaiDTddCA)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this actually seems pretty logical

String literals have all the same methods that `String` objects do, so for example `'a'.split` and `new String('a').split` both exist, you can use them at runtime and nothing breaks. And in typescript if one object has all properties that another object has, then the latter is assignable to the former.

About comparisons: typescript doesn't really control them, it doesn't search for errors like you comparing `'a'` and `new String('a')` and getting that they are not equal

About `instanceof`: it is not always the case that if you define a variable `let a: SomeObjectType`, expression `a instanceof SomeObjectType` will return true.

Consider this example:

```
const obj: Object = {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, null)
console.log(obj instanceof Object) // false
```

Or even simpler:

```
class A {
  foo: boolean
}

// this is fine, because { foo: false } has all properties of A
let obj: A = { foo: false } 
console.log(obj instanceof A) // false
```

Comment: So this is where TypeScript basically **falls back to plain JavaScript**. I wish it was smarter than that. Your second snippet is literally transpiled to `let obj = { foo: false }`. I wish it was producing something like: `let obj = Object.assign({new A(), { foo: false })`, then `obj instanceof A` would be true.

Comment: Also, such behavior kind of violates [this statement from the Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards#:~:text=The%20right%20side%20of%20the%20instanceof): *The right side of the instanceof needs to be a constructor function, and TypeScript will narrow down to [...] the type of the function’s prototype property if its type is not `any`*.

Comment: @noseratio, well, if it were transpiled to `Object.assign(blabla)` this would change the behaviour of the code which would violate the 5th non-goal of typescript (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) - do not change behaviour of the code depending on type system. And it doesn't seem to violate the phrase you quoted. Writing `if(obj instanceof A) {...}`, inside the if clause `obj` will be considered instance of A, but if this if clause doesn't fire, then typescript doesn't narrow anything down which seems a correct behaviour

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm rather fluent with modern JavaScript, but I'm new to TypeScript. Coming from C#, it was my (unjustified?) expectation that TypeScript would help with type integrity like that, rather than defaulting to JS 

Comment: @noseratio, well, good luck ;). Types in typescript differ very much from types in C-languages, Java, etc. so maybe you will adapt to this